# Make documents read only based on metadata

Tags: workflow, document-library, permissions, timer-jobs, metadata

We are using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise on-premise. I am looking for the most optimal approach to fulfill our requirements.

Our requirement is to make a document read only when a column\metadata for the document is set to "Archived".

I have thought about creating a timer job that iterates through all documents, and breaks inheritance on the relevant documents, but I am not really satisfied with this approach as it requires a lot of looping and can not be run on demand by end-users.

I have also thought about creating custom workflows, but that will require a lot of work, and my experience with developing workflows is very limited.

Event receivers I don't even want to think about.

So, I am looking for some ideas on how to achieve our goals, hence I turned to the community here. Please advice.

Comment: Look into rights management policies, specifically expiration to move it into a read only archive

Comment: +1 for Eric. Way too many people approach SharePoint challenges with their Programmer-Glasses on. SharePoint has loads of features that help with Document Management. IRM , DLP , Content Organizer etc.